# Is there a simpler way to filter ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with date inputs. In my model, the dates are formatted as such "/Date(123123123123)/". Apparently that's some sort of MVC3 date format, I dunno. I can run that string through Moment, it outputs local datetime just fine. The problem I'm running into is the binding. ng-model="currentNotification.startDate" obviously outputs the "/Date(123123123123)" string.

Ideally I want the prettified Moment string for the input value, but then upon submitting the form, the date would be converted back to the MVC3-style string.
I've seen some information on creating an attribute directive to deal with this, but that just seems overly complicated. I would think this would be a common use case. "I want to display the date as X, but I want to store it as Y."

Comment: Yeah, it is indeed a common use case for adding a `parser` and a `formatter` to the `ng-model`. But that required a directive either attribute, class or element ..

Comment: Maybe it's a bit too intrusive but if you're always interacting with the same microsoft backend which is creating non-compliant / funny JSON you could also decorate $http and handle the transformations before delegation. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator